# Are the following two statements about linear transforms true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> *Are the following statements true?*
>
> A. There is no surjective linear transform from vector space of dimension $n$ to vector space of dimension $n+k$.
>
> B. There is no injective linear transform from vector space of dimension $n+k$ to vector space of dimension $n$.

I am not sure how to prove them although I suspect them to be true. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *[rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)* states that any linear map $T:V\to W$ between finite-dimensional vector spaces satisfies
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(T)+
\DeclareMathOperator{nullity}{nullity}\nullity(T)=
\dim V\tag{1}
$$
where $\rank(T)$ is the dimension of the image of $T$ and $\nullity(T)$ is the dimension of the kernel of $T$.

Now, suppose $\dim V=n$ and $\dim W=n+k$. If $T$ is surjective, then (1) is equivalent to 
$$
n+k+\nullity(T)=n
$$
which implies $\nullity(T)=-k$, an impossibility if $k>0$.

Can you use the rank-nullity theorem to solve part B?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $k$ is meant to be a positive integer.  Hint: a vector space of dimension $n$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors, but not more.